# Newrelic Python API - send event without exception

Tags: python, newrelic

There is a function called `record_exception()` that you can use if you want to send an error to newrelic.

The question is how to record an error when you don't have an exception in hand? I just want to decide somewhere in the code to record an event to newrelic.

Answer (score 0):

To record generic events that are not errors, you can create a custom metric and then use [`record_custom_metric`](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/agents/python-agent/customization-extension/python-custom-metrics-api#record_custom_metric), like this:

```
newrelic.agent.record_custom_metric('Custom/MyValue', 42)
```

Please see the [naming reference](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/plugins/plugin-developer-resources/developer-reference/metric-naming-reference) to make sure you are naming the metric correctly.